# How to change class name after X seconds of time using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to loop the class name 'move' over all the divs, so if the first div has the class name 'move', i want to  remove it and then  add it to the next element in every three seconds

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {

               setInterval(swapUsp, 3000);

               function swapUsp() {

                   var active = $('#infobarContainer .uspTag');
                   var next = ($('#infobarContainer .uspTag').next().length > 0) ? $('#infobarContainer .uspTag').next() : $('#infobarContainer .uspTag:first');
                   if (active.hasClass('move')) {
                       active.removeClass('move')
                           next.addClass('move');
                   }
                  
               }
           });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="infobarContainer">
  <div class="uspTag tagline tagline2 move">
                          USP 1

                        </div>
                        <div class="uspTag tagline tagline2">
                           USP 2
                        </div>
                          <div class="uspTag tagline tagline2">
                           
                          USP 3
                        </div>
                          <div class="uspTag tagline tagline2">
                          USP 4
                        </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: In your HTML `infobarContainer` is a class, but your jQuery selector is looking for an ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const divs=[...document.querySelectorAll(".tagline2")]; 
divs.i=0;
setInterval(function(){
 divs[divs.i++].classList.remove("move");
 divs[divs.i=divs.i%divs.length].classList.add("move")
},500);
```

```css
.move {background-color:red}
```

```html
<div class="infobarContainer">
  <div class="uspTag tagline tagline2 move">
    USP 1
  </div>
  <div class="uspTag tagline tagline2">
    USP 2
  </div>
  <div class="uspTag tagline tagline2">
    USP 3
  </div>
  <div class="uspTag tagline tagline2">
    USP 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change your ready function to

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
               setInterval(swapUsp, 3000);
               function swapUsp() {
                   var active = $('#infobarContainer .uspTag.move').first();
                   var next = ($('#infobarContainer .uspTag.move').next().length > 0) ? $('#infobarContainer .uspTag.move').next() : $('#infobarContainer .uspTag:first');
                   active.removeClass('move')
                   next.addClass('move');
               }
           });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one with less DOM queries

```
const startAnimation = (time) => {
  let counter = 0;
  const elements = $('.uspTag');
  const update = () => {
    const index = counter % elements.length;
    const previousIndex = ++counter % elements.length;
    $(elements[index]).toggleClass('move');
    $(elements[previousIndex]).toggleClass('move');
  }
  setInterval(update, 3000);
}


startAnimation(3000)
```